# Convert string to type of another variable

Tags: c#, casting

If I have a variable "param" that can be either an int, double, or string, how do I assign another string to param in the most efficient way? Currently what I'm doing is something like this:

```
string s = "5";

switch (param)
{
    case param.GetType() == "System.Double":
        param = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        break;
    case param.GetType() == "System.Int32":
        param = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        break;
    case param.GetType() == "System.String":
    default:
        break;
}
```

I was hoping to condense it to something like this (pseudo-code):

```
param = (typeof(param))s;
```

or

```
param = s as typeof(param);
```

Comment: Instead of relying on [Magic Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), I'd highly recommend you use the [TypeCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Try from this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use 
`Convert.ChangeType(s,param.GetType())`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx

or

`ConvertTo(s,param.GetType())`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13battt(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your overall goal is with just this piece of code, but you can always just change the type of the variable:

```
Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(param));
```

After which, you can simply assign it.

After thinking about it, you can then just go ahead and use your variable now if it's successful.